# I want to execute a function when new dom elements are added somewhere in the body

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, listen

I would like to execute a function when new dom elements are added via ajax, somewhere in the body, by a 3er party JS.

The function i want to execute is jqueryui's tooltip(), which changes title attribute into nice tooltips.

The problem happens when a 3rd party JS adds new elements to many differents div's, and the new element's 'title' attribute  are not being substituted by tooltips. So I need to do again:

```
$('*').tooltip()
```

I think I need something checking if new elements have been added to the body, and run the function on them.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is the 3rd party javascript that is adding the elements using `jQuery` to add them?

Comment: no... it is xajax, or maybe another unknown

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [liveQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same in one of my project which is I needed to listen to the DOM changes., e.g. DOM append, remove, attribute, and data changes.

Actually, the browser itself provides the native function/DOM changes listener which is the **["Mutation Observer"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)**.

These links WILL help you :

1. https://github.com/kapetan/jquery-observe
2. [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242)
3. https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutationobserver